# Server 2008 R2 - Allow UPS to wake computer?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ups, electrical-power

I have a single Windows Server 2008 R2 box that's on a generic Geek Squad battery backup. (That purchase was not my choice.) It shuts down fine when the battery hits a critical level, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to boot back up when the power comes back on. I tried to follow the instructions as outlined here - http://wiert.me/2010/06/24/using-a-usb-connected-apc-ups-with-windows-server-2008-and-vmware-server-2-0/ - but when I go into the Device Manager and open the properties for the HID UPS Battery device, I get no Power Management tab, so I don't see an option anywhere to allow the device to wake the computer.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

If the machine is *shutting down*, as opposed to going into standby or hibernation, then it wouldn't matter what the power management setting is for that device, because the machine is shut down. To power it back up, you need something at the bios level like a KVM or Wake On LAN. If these servers run Intel processors equipped with vPro, you can leverage that technology as well.

As for why the Power Management Tab isn't there, I believe that's based on the device actually implementing power management settings, see [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/551909/windows-7-sleep-requires-graphics-driver/554802#554802) in addition to [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff564538(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Is your BIOS set to restart on power being restored?  Some BIOS defaults to "remain off" rather than "turn on" or "previous state".

Comment: There's no BIOS to set. It's running on a Mac Mini Server. (It's a long story, and it's not what I would have wanted.)

Comment: A quick search online showed that in OSX you can set it.  But I suspect windows wouldn't know anything about the settings in the SMU.  might try booting up in OSX on another drive (yeah, I know its a PITA to swap the drive...) and giving the setting a shot.  It should be in systems prefs -> Energy Saver -> "Start up automatically after a power failure".  Once set, this should be written to the hardware and survive a hard drive swap. (It shouldn't care waht OS it is running when power is restored).  It's worth a shot, though a pain to test.  (I have one in my rack too, but it is running OSX)

Comment: I've got it set up to dual-boot into OSX if I need to... I'm going to give that a shot - what you are saying makes perfect sense, based on what I know about how Macs handle booting and such. Thanks so much for this... I'll let you know how it goes.